# Azure blob trigger, how to trigger on "move" for a file?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

So I have a blob trigger and recently discovered if I have a file and I move it to the folder in question, it does not trigger the blob trigger. How can I trigger off of a "move".
Context - The blob trigger is looking for a json file. It DOES recognize if I copy/ drag and drop from other folder on PC via upload and I overwrite, but NOT if the file is new!
How I have come across this is having an "a" folder and my trigger folder. If I DO NOT have the file in my trigger file and I perform a "move" from file "a" to my trigger folder. This is ignored by the blob trigger? Why is that? Is there a work around?

As far as code, I have to clean it up some but it's a general consumption blob trigger that's connected to look for a json file. It's a ADLS Gen 2 storage account. It DOES work on other blob copies and such. Just NOT on moves.

So far I have tried to move the file and it never triggers but if I copy, drag and drop WITH overwrite, it triggers. Looked through config and checked documents and can't find any mention yet.

Comment: You should be using webhooks and Event Grid in azure to subscribe to storage account events.

Comment: That was an idea that I had! But wasn't sure if blob had a fix!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, this works fine. I'm using ADLS Gen 2 storage account. Even after moving from a different folder to trigger folder, it is getting triggered. I made sure about this after attaching the storage account with function app and logic app. Below is the ***function.json*** for my function app.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myBlob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "input/{name}.json",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]

Make sure the extension that you have added for filter is in the right format to get it triggered.